# Perl, using for loop to parse paragraphs into multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, perl, for-loop, multidimensional-array, text

I've been trying to make something work and I just can't seem to get it. What I'm trying to do... I have a text file that has multiple "sections" delimited by section headers:

```
object-group network A
 description description of section A
 network-object host A.B.C.D
 network-object AA.BB.CC.DD MM.MM.MM.MM
object-group network B
 description description of section B
 network-object host e.f.g.h
 network-object host i.j.k.l
```

I'm trying to eventually end up with a multidimensional array that will give me:

```
A, description, A.B.C.D, host
A, description, AA.BB.CC.DD, MM.MM.MM.MM
B, description, e.f.g.h, host
B, description, i.j.k.l, host
```

I haven't even gotten to the point of reformatting the data yet as I can't even get it to properly parse the line of the text file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = '/root/vpnstuff/objectgroups';
my @sections;
my $section;

open my $FILE, '<', "$file" or die "$file: $!";

while(<$FILE>){
    chomp;
    push @sections, [split /object-group.[a-z|A-Z|0-9][\s\S]*?(?=\n.*?object-group|$)/, $_];
}

print Dumper( @sections ) , "\n\n";

for $section (@sections){
    for my $line (@$section){
        print $line, "\n";
    }
}
```

However, what this does is on account of the split function, strips out the "object-group network XX" headers. What I was originally planning to do was to parse the text file, using grep to dump the sections into an array, and then loop through each item in the array to re-format them into what I've described above...

Normally my google kung fu is pretty good, but I'm having real trouble wrapping my head around this one.

---

EDIT. Thanks to all who responded, and thanks to @zdim for helping point me in the right direction. Here's where I ended up, I'm sure you call could have done it much cleaner, but it works, and now I can use it as a working example for the other 3-4000 lines of config I have to parse.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = '/root/vpnstuff/objectgroups';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my (@sections, @base, $got_description);

while (<$fh>)
{
    my @fields = split;

    if ($fields[0] eq 'object-group') {
        @base = ();
        push @base, $fields[-1];
        $got_description = 0;
    }
    elsif (not $got_description) {
        $got_description = 1;
        if ($fields[0] eq 'description') {
            push @base, join ' ', @fields[1..$#fields];
        }
        elsif ($fields[0] ne 'description') {
            if ($fields[1] eq 'host') {
                push @base, "";
                push @sections, [ @base, $fields[2], $fields[1] ];
            }
            else {
                push @base, "";
                push @sections, [ @base, $fields[1], $fields[2] ];
            }
        }
    }
    elsif ($fields[1] eq 'host') {
        push @sections, [ @base, $fields[2], $fields[1] ];
    }
    elsif ($fields[1] ne 'host') {
        push @sections, [ @base, $fields[1], $fields[2] ];
    }
}

say join ', ', @$_ for @sections;
```

Comment: `[a-z|A-Z|0-9]` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9|]`. `[\s\S]` is the same as `.` if you enable the `/s` flag.

Comment: (1) Is the line "_description ..._" always the first line after "_object-group_", and has no keywords?  (2) Do other lines always have the format your sample shows ("_network-object_" with either "_host A.B.._" or "_AA.BB..  MM.MM.._")?  (3) Is it always exactly one pair of phrases after "_network-object_"? (4) Can the file ever be very large (as in many, many Mb)?

Comment: Is there a design reason for having an array-of-arrays for each line, or would not hashrefs in an array be better, for instance `( { A => [ description, ... ] },  ...)`?

Comment: Thanks zdim. To answer your questions above. 1) no "description" is not always present; 2) yes the other lines always have the same format; 3) no the number of lines is almost always different; 4) no, the file will never be multiple MB... we're talking about around 1000 lines on average; 5) no design reason for array of arrays, just happened to be the first solution my mind came to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you process the file line-by-line that regex in `split` cannot process ... multiple lines.  Also, using `split` like that is a bit convoluted (what exactly does it return?) while not necessary.

You can parse the whole  multi-line block in a single regex, but for that you'd need to read the whole file into a scalar (to "slurp" it), and that regex wouldn't be exactly simple either.

For a line-by-line approach a flag is needed to know about "the first" line after the header, what seems to be how the description line is identified.  Each line is first `split` and then the fields used for logic,
so that we wouldn't start the regex engine often.

The object-name and the description are stored in an ancillary array as they are used for all others.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = 'data.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my (@sections, @base, $got_description);

while (<$fh>) 
{
    my @fields = split;

    if ($fields[0] eq 'object-group') {
        @base = (); 
        push @base, $fields[-1];
        $got_description = 0;
    }   
    elsif (not $got_description) { 
        $got_description = 1;
        push @base, join ' ', @fields;
    }   
    elsif ($fields[1] eq 'host') {
        push @sections, [ @base, $fields[2], $fields[1] ];
    } 
    else {
        push @sections, [ @base, $fields[1], $fields[2] ]; 
    }   
}

say join ', ', @$_ for @sections;
```

On entering a new object-group block the ancillary array used for the name and description (`@base`) need be cleared, as well as the description-flag.

You can also test the format of lines other than the header and the first line, with regex for patterns `A.B...`, `AA.BB..`, and `MM.MM..`. I didn't do that so not to guess what these stand for.

This code clearly makes assumptions about data since specs aren't stated. The object-group name is taken to be the last word on its line and other values are also taken to have no spaces.

With the description line from your sample shortened, this prints

```
A, description of A, A.B.C.D, host
A, description of A, AA.BB.CC.DD, MM.MM.MM.MM
B, description of B, e.f.g.h, host
B, description of B, i.j.k.l, host
```

Comment: Worked, Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

I would break it into sections and then work with the data. It's almost always easier to work with the whole block of text in one variable, rather than lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp;
my @arr;
my $var = read_file($filename);
for (split  "object-group " , $var ) 
{ 
 my $text.=$1 if /^network (\S+)/s; 
 $text.=", $1" if / description (.*)/; 
 push @arr, "$text , $1, $2" while / network-object ((?:\w+\.){3}\w+) ((?:\w+\.){3}\w+)/g;
 push @arr, "$text , $1, $2" while / network-object (host) ((?:\w+\.){3}\w+)/g ;
}
$"=")\n(";
print "(@arr)\n";'
```

Comment: Thanks Hoff, I'll give this a go too!

Comment: *"It's almost always easier to work with the whole block of text in one variable, rather than lines"* That is complete nonsense. It is very rarely "easier" and usually results in opaque code such as you have written here.

Comment: @Borodin how so, in configs such as this, there are always a fix number of options and the data is consistent. when you have the options in one place use //m and //s really makes sure youre checking exactly the right bit and not drifting into a new section. You can add the data verification easily too to avoid potential issues.